# If $X$ is dense in $Y$, can I construct a neighborhood of only $x\in X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am working through proofs in some graduate lecture notes and I am sure there is some Analysis or Topology result that I can't remember, so does anyone what the answer to the following question is?

Let a $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $X$ be dense in $Y$.  Given an element $y \in Y$,  does there exist a neighborhood around $y$ which contains only elements in $X$?

Thanks!

Comment: No, not necessarily. (Also, I assume you mean "which contains only elements in $X$ *except possibly* $y$ itself", because otherwise it's silly)

Comment: Take, for example, $Y=\mathbb R$ and $X=\mathbb Q$

Comment: In general, there is not a $Y$-neighbourhood of $y$ contained in $X$ (in fact, such a neighbourhood exists if and only if $y$ belongs to the interior of $X$).

Comment: @Will M. Do you mind sharing a resource for that result?

Comment: Definition of interior of a set

Answer (score 1):

Each neigborhood of $y$ in $Y$ contains $y$, hence for $y \in Y \setminus X$ it is impossible.

For $y \in X$ it is true if and only if $y$ is an interior point of $X$. In general this will not be the case. For example, $\mathbb Q$ does not have interior points in $\mathbb R$.